# Node.js puppeteer - How to set navigation timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. Some of the files I'm opening are quite large ... and then I get an error:

Error:

```
our error { TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (/project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:74:21)
    at <anonymous> name: 'TimeoutError' }
```

How can I ignore it or set a higher timeout?

That's my script:

```
await page.goto('url'+tableCell04Val, {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

Comment: You can read the docs https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout

Comment: @katmanco please update docs link

Comment: @MuhammadUzair thanks for warning :)  here is the up-to-date docs https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setdefaultnavigationtimeout

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use `timeout: 0` to disable timeout errors if you're loading a heavy page.

Use it in your `page.goto` like:

```
await page.goto('url'+tableCell04Val, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
```

[You can see the PR made to Pupeteer here which added the change, along with documentation and the unit tests that implement it.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/commit/53531c9a92e06e4202883543f5ef330bd5b83afa)

Comment: Its working for direct pages, but not for the oauth redirect pages.

Comment: Do you have a solution for that @MohanBabu?

Comment: i cannot able to catch the flow. so reopen the same url and i was able to load the page successfully with catched token on the browser and installed some fonts causing the page blank.

Answer (score 74):

#UPDATE 2019 (still working 2022)

You can also change the page behaviour since V1.0.0:

```js
page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
```

The param is the timeout in milliseconds.

References:
https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setdefaultnavigationtimeout

Answer (score 42):

There are two methods to handle the timeouts in Puppeteer:

**a)** `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeoutInMiliseconds)`

It affects the navigation-related functions:

```
•   page.goBack([options])
•   page.goForward([options])
•   page.goto(url[, options])
•   page.reload([options])
•   page.setContent(html[, options])
•   page.waitForNavigation([options])
```

**b)** `page.setDefaultTimeout(timeoutInMiliseconds)`

It affects all the previous navigation functions plus all the Waiting funtions:

```
•   page.waitFor(selectorOrFunctionOrTimeout[, options[, ...args]])
•   page.waitForFunction(pageFunction[, options[, ...args]])
•   page.waitForRequest(urlOrPredicate[, options])
•   page.waitForResponse(urlOrPredicate[, options])
•   page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])
•   page.waitForXPath(xpath[, options])
```

**NOTE**: `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout` takes priority over `page.setDefaultTimeout`

Comment: In some situation, only .setDefaultTimeout( would work. I just spent half a day for this.

Answer (score 11):

You can set timeout like this

```
await page.goto('url'+tableCell04Val, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000}).then(() => {
    console.log('success')
}).catch((res) => {
    console.log('fails', res)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

```
await page.goto('url'+tableCell04Val, {  waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 0});
```

> networkidle2 comes handy for pages that do long-polling or any other side activity.

Check https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1552#issuecomment-350954419

Answer (score 8):

The default in puppeteer timeout is 30 seconds. To use custom timeouts, you can use the setDefaultNavigationTimeout and setDefaultTimeout methods or the timeout property in the options parameter. The wait time in all cases is specified in milliseconds.

```
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
```

e.g.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();            
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000); //timeout 60 seconds now
```

Pass 0 to disable the timeout

```
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
```

Comment: No need to `await` on timeout sets. They don't return promises.

Answer (score -2):

I got same error but not on directly using node.js application. I faced this issue when I was using [MagePack](https://github.com/magesuite/magepack) installed on the Ubuntu server.

I fixed it by increasing the timeout in the following file */ur/local/lib/node_modules/magepack/node_modules/puppeteer/libTimeoutSettings.js*

```
const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30000
```

*Note*: It may not be perfect solution but it worked for me and fixed the issue  which I was facing.

Comment: this is not a solution ... If the job is greater than the previous than it will agains say timeout

Comment: @AliYarKhan It may not be a proper solution but it worked in my case.

Comment: What happens when you reinstall the project in a different environment? You'd lose the hack. It's difficult to maintain such a code base.

Comment: @andromeda I have already mentioned that it may not be a perfect solution but works for me. The node js is installed on the server and there is a Php application which uses a part of it for deployment process. All better solutions are welcome by me.